# How to add and run project barcodescanner from GitHub to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, barcode-scanner

I found this project 
https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner
Unfortunately I'm  novice to eclipse and Java.
I google that I have to use gradle. That's ok I installed gradle and gradle eclipse plugin. But I don't know what I have to do further for build project and import it to eclipse. Maybe some body can show me the way to google or give instruction of building and running this project. Thanks